# How to validate a particular row among many rows?

Tags: c#, winium

How to validate a particular row data among many rows in the table for testing in c# and once if all the data are verified than test case is passed and if not verified then fail?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Winium;

namespace SFGridDataTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            DesktopOptions options = new DesktopOptions();
            options.ApplicationPath = @"C:\Users\windev\Desktop\WPF\bin\Debug\SfDataGridDemo.exe";
            WiniumDriver driver = new WiniumDriver(@"C:\Users\windev\Desktop\DemoWPF\Winium.Desktop.Driver", options);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            driver.FindElementById("btn_Close").Click();
            AutomationElement desktop = AutomationElement.RootElement;

            //AutomationElement of SfDataGrid.
            AutomationElement datagrid = desktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "sfgrid"));

            //AutomationElement of GridCell in SfDataGrid
            var cellAutomationElement = desktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Cell1"));
            var cellAutomationElement1 = desktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Cell2"));
            var cellAutomationElement2 = desktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Cell3"));
            var cellAutomationElement3 = desktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Cell4"));
            var cellAutomationElement4 = desktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Cell5"));

            //AutomationElement of Row in SfDataGrid
            var row = desktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "Row1"));

            //Loctating the automation id for the each cell
            AutomationElement.AutomationElementInformation currentAutomationElement = cellAutomationElement.Current;
            AutomationElement.AutomationElementInformation currentAutomationElement1 = cellAutomationElement1.Current;
            AutomationElement.AutomationElementInformation currentAutomationElement2 = cellAutomationElement2.Current;
            AutomationElement.AutomationElementInformation currentAutomationElement3 = cellAutomationElement3.Current;
            AutomationElement.AutomationElementInformation currentAutomationElement4 = cellAutomationElement4.Current;

            //extracting each value from the cells
            string[] array = currentAutomationElement.ItemStatus.Split(new string[]
            {
            "#"
            }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string[] array1 = currentAutomationElement1.ItemStatus.Split(new string[]
            {
            "#"
            }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string[] array2 = currentAutomationElement2.ItemStatus.Split(new string[]
            {
            "#"
            }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string[] array3 = currentAutomationElement3.ItemStatus.Split(new string[]
            {
            "#"
            }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string[] array4 = currentAutomationElement4.ItemStatus.Split(new string[]
            {
            "#"
            }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            //Storing the each value of cells
            var cellValue = array[0];
            var cellValue1 = array1[0];
            var cellValue2 = array2[0];
            var cellValue3 = array3[0];
            var cellValue4 = array4[0];
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cell Zero: " + cellValue);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cell One: " + cellValue1);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cell Two: " + cellValue2);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cell Three: " + cellValue3);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cell Four: " + cellValue4);
            Assert.IsTrue(cellValue == "1001");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Full Row Data: " + cellValue + " " + cellValue1 + " " + cellValue2 + " " + cellValue3 + " " + cellValue4);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: when you run the test what is it returning?

Comment: Try to edit the code to only the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to have many internal representations that are not easy to interpret for someone outside your project; so I will suggest something in general:

Let's say:
1 - A row is located by the tr tag.
2 - The row has two cells, located by the classes .cell1 and .cell2

You want to check the data of the row which cell1 is enabled.

You would do:

```
// Grab all the rows
rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr"));

// Filter the rows by the enabled criteria, grabbing the first matching row
enabledRow = rows.filter( row => row.findElement(".cell1").isEnabled())[0];

// Checks the data
assertEquals( enabledRow.findElement(".cell1").text, "Cell 1");
assertEquals( enabledRow.findElement(".cell2").text, "Cell 2");
```